# I am unable to get pattern highlighted in log file using Ideolog Plugin in PyCharm

Tags: python, logging, pycharm, python-logging

I have the following lines in my log file

```
[18-09-2020-13:29:03:165 INFO] clicking on Gmail link on Google Home Page
[18-09-2020-13:29:05:297 DEBUG] Test_demo1.py:22:test_tc1: googlePage.py:13:func1: webActions.py:83:clickOnElement: => clicked on element : //a[text()='Gmail']
[18-09-2020-13:29:05:309 INFO] clicking on Sign in link on Gmail Home Page
[18-09-2020-13:29:07:562 DEBUG] Test_demo1.py:22:test_tc1: googlePage.py:19:func1: webActions.py:96:waitAndSendKeysOnElement: => entered text in element : //input[@id='identifierId']
[18-09-2020-13:29:07:642 DEBUG] Test_demo1.py:22:test_tc1: googlePage.py:20:func1: webActions.py:83:clickOnElement: => clicked on element : //div[@id='identifierNext']
[18-09-2020-13:29:18:059 ERROR] Exception occured in => Test_demo1.py:22:test_tc1: googlePage.py:21:func1: webActions.py:100:waitAndSendKeysOnElement:
[18-09-2020-13:29:18:060 ERROR] Unable to enter text in element : //input[@type='password']
[18-09-2020-13:29:18:061 ERROR] TimeoutException : Message:
```

I have added Ideolog plugin in PyCharm and using the below

Message pattern `[\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{4}\-\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{3}\s([A-Z]{4,8})]\s(.*)$`

Message start pattern `^\[`

Time format `d-m-Y-H:M:S`

Time Capture Group `0`

Severity Capture Group `0`

Category Capture Group `0`

Pattern

`^\s*E(RROR)?\s*$` -> Highlight line (Foreground, #FF0000)

`^\s*W(ARN(ING)?)?\s*$` -> Highlight line (Foreground, #FFAA00)

`^\s*I(NFO)?\s*$` -> Highlight line (Foreground, #3FBF3F)

I am still unable to get the INFO and ERROR statements highlighted in my log file

Can someone please let me know how to correctly configure the message patterns so as to match my log file and how to get it highlighted?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In you case use

Message pattern: `^\[(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}-\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{3})\s([^]]+)].+$`

Message start pattern `^\[`

Time format `dd-MM-yyyy-HH:mm:ss:SSS`

Time Capture Group `1`

Severity Capture Group `2`

Category Capture Group `0`